# Why is the Observable and subscriber for an array not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, typescript, observable

I am trying to write a simple error handling service. It can receive errors and add them in an array but for some reason, it is not working.

> errorhandling.service

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlingService {
    private errors: Array<ErrorMessage>;

    constructor() {
        this.errors = new Array<ErrorMessage>();
    }

    getErrors(): Observable<Array<ErrorMessage>>{
        return Observable.of(this.errors);
    }

    handleError(error: Response, errorText: string) {
        let errorMessage = this.createErrorMessage(error);
        errorMessage.displayText = errorText;
        this.errors.push(errorMessage);
    }

    private createErrorMessage(error: Response): ErrorMessage {
        let errorMessage: ErrorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
        errorMessage.errorType = error.type;
        errorMessage.statusCode = error.status;
        return errorMessage;
    }
}

export class ErrorMessage {
    statusCode: number;
    displayText: string;
    errorType: ResponseType;
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    errorMessage: Message[] = [];
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private renderer: Renderer, private errorhandlingService: ErrorHandlingService) {
        localStorage.removeItem(AppConstants.authenticationLocalStorageKey);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.errorhandlingService.getErrors().subscribe(errorMessages =>{
            let errorMessage: ErrorMessage = errorMessages.pop();
            console.log(errorMessage);
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage ? [{ severity: 'error', summary: '', detail: errorMessage.displayText }] : [];
        });
    }

    onDeactivate() {
        //scroll to top of page after routing
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(document.body, "scrollTop", 0);
    }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 well center-text">
            <p-messages [value]="errorMessage"></p-messages>
            <router-outlet (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
```

The code below is in another component which triggers the errorhandling service method.

> businessArea.component.ts

```
this.businessAreaService.getBusinessAreaById(id)
                    .subscribe(businessArea => {
                        this.model = businessArea;
                    },
                    error => this.errorHandlingService.handleError(error, 'Could not load Business Area'));
```

**Edit**: I tried many things like Observable, but it didn't work as well. I am not sure what is the subject and how to use it but it seems that Observable makes sense in my scenario. Any useful link will help as well? I can breakpoint and I can see it hit the method and then it pushes the Error in the array but subscribe on app.component is never called.

**expected behaviour:**
When `this.businessAreaService.getBusinessAreaById` is called in an error case it calls `errorHandlingService.handleError` which logs the error in an array in errorHandlingService by calling the method `this.errorHandlingService.handleError`. Now I have a subscriber in **app.component** which should be called when an error is added to an array, so that I can display error in a div.

**What is not working:**
When an element/error is added to the array in errorhandling service, the subscriber on the app.component.ts is not called. Shouldn't adding element in array trigger subscriber? It is only called the first time when ngOnit is called. After any subsequent errors subscriber is not called. Although I can see the error being pushed in the array.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what function is not working and what you are expecting it to do?

Comment: @Raven I have edited my question, I am not sure what else i can write to explain better. you think my edit makes sense?

Comment: yes everything is working fine. when I run the app i get undefined in console.log because there are no errors but on subsequent calls, it doesn't log anything. its like subscriber is not called 2nd and above time

Comment: Thanks, the edit did clear things up. I am sure you are creating the observable the wrong way for it to listen to changes. Let me look something up

Comment: I am pretty sure, I am doing some fundamental mistake. I have read many docs and they all suggest Observable.of or Observable.from...but it seems after first time Observable doesnt trigger for subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Subject` to achieve it, update the code inside your service class like below, you don't have to modify anything else except for the service class

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlingService {
    private errors: Array<ErrorMessage>;
    private broadcaster = new Subject<Array<ErrorMessage>>();

    constructor() {
        this.errors = new Array<ErrorMessage>();
    }

    getErrors(): Subject<Array<ErrorMessage>>{
        return this.broadcaster;
    }

    handleError(error: Response, errorText: string) {
        let errorMessage = this.createErrorMessage(error);
        errorMessage.displayText = errorText;
        this.errors.push(errorMessage);
        // letting all subscribers know of the new change
        this.broadcaster.next(this.errors);
    }

    private createErrorMessage(error: Response): ErrorMessage {
        let errorMessage: ErrorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
        errorMessage.errorType = error.type;
        errorMessage.statusCode = error.status;
        return errorMessage;
    }
}

export class ErrorMessage {
    statusCode: number;
    displayText: string;
    errorType: ResponseType;
}
```

Comment: sure will try it, what is the difference between subject and observable? sorry i am new to these concepts

Comment: Ah.. I just switched from mobile to desktop to post this answer. Please do use the proper import `import { Subject } from '@reactivex/rxjs/es6/Subject.js'` to avoid any issues with tree-shaking.

Comment: `Subject` is *similar* to `Observable` in the sense that `Subject` allows you to subscribe to it to listen for updates, however, `Subject`s don't offer those operators that `Observable`s do, and you have to manually call `next` on `Subject` to push changes down to the subscribers

Comment: [`Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) is a simple implementation of the `create` function. To add to this answer the original implementation using `Observable.of` does not include any logic to push new values in the stream. Here `.next()` is used to push the variable in the stream.

Comment: @Raven `Observable` does not have a `next` method

Comment: @Dummy Sure. It inherits the `.onNext()` functionality from the `Observer`. Your example does include a `Subject.next()` though so that might be a typo

Comment: @Raven typo where?

Comment: @Raven  `next` **is**  an instance method on `Subject`

Comment: I could not find it back in the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md). Does that mean both `onNext` and `next` functions exist on a `Subject`? Is there a difference?

Comment: Functionally no difference, I assume `next` is the public API to send updates to subscribers while `onNext` is internal

Comment: can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433779/angular2-testing-stubbing-service-method-is-undefined